# jquery $(window).width() returning different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

I am trying to fit some HTML blocks in the full width of the window.
But the value I get seems to be wrong in the first milliseconds...

For testing I included a second script test.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    console.log($(window).width());
});
```

And my original script starts with:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    console.log($(window).width());
    ... math stuff ...
});
```

The output in the console is:

```
1432 blockraster-autowidth.js
1415 test.js
```

I occasionally found that including my script twice like

```
<script src="js/blockraster-autowidth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/blockraster-autowidth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Brings up an output like this, making my script working properly (wich is obviously no solution):

```
1432 blockraster-autowidth.js
1415 blockraster-autowidth.js
1415 test.js
```

So it seems like the first script executed does not get the right value.
I even tried `setTimeout` and `$(window).ready()` instead of `document` but the output stays the same.

I also read about a missing DOCTYPE but that did not change anything.

Comment: provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [weave](http://liveweave.com/), etc. so we can retrace your issue.

Comment: Images and resources probably haven't loaded yet. Replace `document.ready` with `$(window).on('load')` instead

Comment: `$(window).on('load')` Did it. Tanks, that was easy!

Comment: Could be scrollbar offset?